Calling variables in latex via newcommands arguments
I want to make my life easier with some calculations in LaTex, therefore I define a compound specific variablecalled \compound1molarmass. I use \newcommand to call another function from chemmacros so I need #1 to be compound1. To perform the calculation I need to call \compound1molarmass and I want to use #1 from \newcommand to do so.
So something like \csname #1molarmass\endcsname so that it's interpreted as \compound1molarmass. The following code doesnt work unfortunatley.
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{calculator}

\def\compound1molarmass{2}
\newcommand{\cmpd}[2]{\DIVIDE{#2}{\csname #1molarmass\endcsname}{\res}\res}

\begin{document}

\cmpd{compound1}{4}

\end{document}

Ideally this code would output something like 2 as a value.
Running this code leady to many undefined control sequences.

you would need \ExpandArgs{c}\def{compound1molarmass}{2} or similar as you can not have digits in command names but it would be much simpler to just use a different name without the digit

You cannot really do \def\compound1molarmass, because macro names can only consist of letters (or a single nonletter). You might do
\expandafter\def\csname compound1molarmass\endcsname{2}

but there are much better methods.
I suggest

not to use \def;
not to use calculator.

Regarding 1, it's better to use “names” rather than macros; about 2, the LaTeX kernel has (almost) full management of floating point expressions.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% this substitutes your \def
\NewDocumentCommand{\definecompoundmass}{mm}
 {% #1 = compound name, #2 = mass
  \fp_zero_new:c { l_hugel_cmpd_#1_fp }
  \fp_set:cn { l_hugel_cmpd_#1_fp } { #2 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\cmpd}{mom}
 {% #1 = compound name, #2 = number of digits to round at, #3 = factor
  \IfNoValueTF { #2 }
   {% no rounding
    \fp_eval:n { (#3)/\fp_use:c { l_hugel_cmpd_#1_fp } }
   }
   {% rounding
    \fp_eval:n { round( (#3)/\fp_use:c { l_hugel_cmpd_#1_fp } , #2 ) }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definecompoundmass{compound1}{2}
\definecompoundmass{compound2}{3.12344}

\begin{document}

\cmpd{compound1}{4} % no rounding

\cmpd{compound2}{3} % no rounding

\cmpd{compound2}[2]{3} % round at two digits

\end{document}


Allocations of variables storing masses is local to the group in which they appear, but I believe it's better to define them in the preamble, where you can easily find them.

\def\compound1molarmass{2} defines the control word token \compound to be delimited by the character tokens 112m11o11l11a11r11m11a11s11s11 and to expand to the character token 212.
Therefore \csname #1molarmass\endcsname does not work out as with #1 being compound1 the \csname..\endcsname-expression yields a control word token \compound1molarmass which is undefined.
As suggested by David Carlisle you can use \ExpandArgs / \UseName for having the control word token \compound1molarmass constructed from character tokens that form its name prior to defining/using it:
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{calculator}

%\ExplSyntaxOn
%\cs_new_eq:NN \UseName \use:c
%\cs_new:Npn \ExpandArgs #1
%  {
%    \cs_if_exist_use:cF { exp_args:N #1 }
%    { \msg_expandable_error:nnn { kernel } { unknown-arg-expansion } {#1} }
%  }
%\msg_new:nnn { kernel } { unknown-arg-expansion }{ Unknown~arg~expansion~"#1" }
%\ExplSyntaxOff

\ExpandArgs{Nc}\newcommand*{compound1molarmass}{2}
%\newcommand{\cmpd}[2]{\DIVIDE{#2}{\csname #1molarmass\endcsname}{\res}\res}
\newcommand{\cmpd}[2]{\DIVIDE{#2}{\UseName{#1molarmass}}{\res}\res}
%\newcommand{\cmpd}[2]{\ExpandArgs{nc}\DIVIDE{#2}{#1molarmass}{\res}\res}

\begin{document}

\cmpd{compound1}{4}

\end{document}

